# (SQL) Create Table with Distances from Separate Table with XY Coordinates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dataset, coordinates

I am trying to create a table that will have unique distances between slot machines based on the following dataset.

[image]

I know I first need to calculate my distances and the only way I currently know how would be to use the following code:

```
select (SELECT abs(p1.coordinate_x - p2.coordinate_x) + abs(p1.coordinate_y - p2.coordinate_y)) as Distance
FROM dim_slot_coordinates p1
CROSS JOIN dim_slot_coordinates p2
WHERE p1.slot_machine_id = 1 and p2.slot_machine_id = 2
```

But this obviously only returns the distance between the first two machines. How do I calculate the distances between all of the machines? Then, how would I properly make sure each distance is unique?

What would be the easiest way to do this in SQL?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Please add sample as text and also dedired results [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What do you mean by ensuring that the distances are unique?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: the resulting table should have unique values for the distances between each machine. Thank you for the help. Is there a way to add anything to the query in order for this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply use a `cross join`:

```
select p1.slot_machine_id, p2.slot_machine_id,
       (abs(p1.coordinate_x - p2.coordinate_x) + abs(p1.coordinate_y - p2.coordinate_y)) as Distance
from dim_slot_coordinates p1 CROSS JOIN 
     dim_slot_coordinates p2;
```

If you wanted the distance between two machines only calculated once, then add an inequality:

```
select p1.slot_machine_id, p2.slot_machine_id,
       (abs(p1.coordinate_x - p2.coordinate_x) + abs(p1.coordinate_y - p2.coordinate_y)) as Distance
from dim_slot_coordinates p1 CROSS JOIN 
     dim_slot_coordinates p2
where p1.slot_machine_id < p2.slot_machine_id;
```

EDIT:

If you want "unique" distances, you could use:

```
select distinct p1.slot_machine_id
       (abs(p1.coordinate_x - p2.coordinate_x) + abs(p1.coordinate_y - p2.coordinate_y)) as Distance
    from dim_slot_coordinates p1 CROSS JOIN 
         dim_slot_coordinates p2
    where p1.slot_machine_id <> p2.slot_machine_id;
```

This doesn't seem useful to me, but it does provide a list of unique distances for each machine.

Comment: Is there any way to modify this query to allow for unique distance values in the resulting table? the distance from Machine 1 to Machine 2 is equal to the distance from Machine 1 to Machine 3. Thank you for your help thus far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just find the distance between all of the machines I would not use a CROSS JOIN, as it will obviously give you all of the combinations.  The reason being, if you require unique distances then you will run into a problem pretty quickly because the distance between machine 1 and machine 2 would be the same as between machine 2 and machine 1.

Using your distance formula this is how I would get the list:

```
CREATE TABLE #dim_slot_coordinates(slot_machine_id int, coordinate_x int, coordinate_y int)
INSERT INTO #dim_slot_coordinates VALUES (1,1,1),(2,2,5),(3,-2,3),(4,-5,-5),(5,5,-3)

   
SELECT p1.slot_machine_id SM1,p2.slot_machine_id SM2, 
    (SELECT abs(p1.coordinate_x - p2.coordinate_x) + abs(p1.coordinate_y - p2.coordinate_y)) as Distance
FROM #dim_slot_coordinates p1
    CROSS APPLY(    
            SELECT * 
                FROM #dim_slot_coordinates 
                WHERE slot_machine_id > p1.slot_machine_id) p2
order by sm1
```

As for *properly make sure each distance is unique* , this sounds like you would want to put a unique constraint on distance in the table you are putting this data into.

Comment: Is there any way to modify this query to allow for unique distance values in the resulting table? the distance from Machine 1 to Machine 2 is equal to the distance from Machine 1 to Machine 3. Thank you for your help thus far.

Comment: I am sure there is, but the question is what do you want to do with the duplicates? Machine 1 to Machine 2 has a duplicate to Machine 1 to Machine 3, so do you only want to keep one? If so which one? Or do you want to remove them both? Please clarify what your expected output is and you will probably get a better answer.